# Switch Tabs Between Monitors

Tags: windows, google-chrome, display, switch, tabs

In my computer science tab I switched my chrome tab to the second monitor (left) but my mouse won't go to that monitor. I tried opening display settings but it's blocked by an administrator. How do I get chrome back to the first monitor (right) without using my mouse or display settings?

Comment: In this case, you should ask for help to your administrator.

Answer (score 0):

move a window to a display located to the left of your current display,
press Windows + Shift + Left Arrow.

move a window to a display located to the right of your current display,
press Windows + Shift + Right Arrow.